# Pandas: Replace missing dataframe values / conditional calculation: fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I want to calculate a pandas dataframe, but some rows contain missing values. For those missing values, i want to use a diffent algorithm. Lets say:

- If column B contains a value, then substract A from B
- If column B does **not** contain a value, then subtract A from C

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[1,1,None,1],'c':[2,2,2,2]})
df['calc'] = df['b']-df['a']
```

results in:

```
print(df)
   a    b  c  calc
0  1  1.0  2   0.0
1  2  1.0  2  -1.0
2  3  NaN  2   NaN
3  4  1.0  2  -3.0
```

**Approach 1:** fill the NaN rows using `.where`:

```
df['calc'].where(df['b'].isnull()) = df['c']-df['a']
```

which results in **SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call**.

**Approach 2:** fill the NaN rows using `.iterrows()`:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    i = df['calc'].iloc[index]

    if pd.isnull(row['b']):
        i = row['c']-row['a']
        print(i)
    else:
        i = row['b']-row['a']
        print(i)
```

is executed without errors and calculation is correct, these `i` values are printed to the console:

```
0.0
-1.0
-1.0
-3.0
```

but the **values are not written into `df['calc']`**, the datafram remains as is:

```
print(df['calc'])
0    0.0
1   -1.0
2    NaN
3   -3.0
```

What is the correct way of overwriting the `NaN` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 2:**

you are assigning it to `i` value. but this won't modify your original dataframe.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    i = df['calc'].iloc[index]

    if pd.isnull(row['b']):
        i = row['c']-row['a']
        print(i)
    else:
        i = row['b']-row['a']
        print(i)
    df.loc[index,'calc'] = i #<------------- here
```

also don't use `iterrows()` it is too slow.

**Approach 1:**
`Pandas where() method is used to check a data frame for one or more condition and return the result accordingly. By default, The rows not satisfying the condition are filled with NaN value.`

it should be:

```
df['calc'] = df['calc'].where(df['b'].isnull(), df['c']-df['a'])
```

but this will only find those row value where you have non zero value and fill that with the given value.

Use:

```
df['calc'] = df['calc'].where(~df['b'].isnull(), df['c']-df['a'])
```

OR

```
df['calc'] = np.where(df['b'].isnull(), df['c']-df['a'], df['calc'])
```

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I stumbled over `.fillna`:

```
df['calc'] = df['calc'].fillna( df['c']-df['a'] )
```

gets the job done! Can anyone explain what is wrong with above two approaches...?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of subtracting `b` from `a` then `c` from `a` **what you can do is first `fill` the `nan` values in column `b` with the values from column `c`, then subtract column `a`:**

```
df['calc'] = df['b'].fillna(df['c']) - df['a']
```

---

```
   a    b  c  calc
0  1  1.0  2   0.0
1  2  1.0  2  -1.0
2  3  NaN  2  -1.0
3  4  1.0  2  -3.0
```